# Files содержит недопустимое значение

Tags: c#, visual-studio, обработка-ошибок

Работаю с Visual Studio 2012, столкнулась с ошибкой:

> Files содержит недопустимое значение "'<непонятная абракадабра на неизвестной кодировке, символы>"

Ошибка появилась после того, как я удалила написанный мной метод, который больше не был нужен в программе. С чем это может быть связано?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пальцами "удалила метод", локтем случайно вбила вместо него "непонятную абракадабру на неизвестной кодировке". Бывает. Идем в указанный файл и удаляем абракадабру.

Comment: Откатите проект к последней работавшей версии и сравните файлы.

Comment: Укажите язык, на котором программируете. С++?

Comment: >>'Пальцами "удалила метод", локтем случайно вбила вместо него "непонятную абракадабру на неизвестной кодировке". '             абракадабра не в методе, а в тексте ошибки. То есть она буквально выглядит, как на скрине. Пишу на С#

Comment: Проблема явно в кодировке. Например, вы читаете из файла в кодировке 1251, а там на самом деле utf-8, или наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

Помогла информация во вкладке Вывод. Там есть информация о файле, в котором проблема. Находим в строчке слово error и ищем информацию об ошибке, номер которой указан. В данном случае - error MSB3541, решением стало удалить папку obj из проекта. После этого все заработало.